# backbone js or knockout js as a web framework with jquery mobile

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, frameworks, knockout.js

without trying to cause a mass discussion I would like some advice from the fellow users of stack overflow.

I am about to start building a mobile website that gets it data from JSON that comes from a PHP rest api.

I have looked into different mobile frameworks and feel that JQM will work best for us as we have the knowledge of jQuery even though a little large.

Currently at work however we are using jQuery for all our sites and realise that now we are building a mobile website I need to think about javascript frameworks to move us onto a more MV* approach, which I understand the benefits of and will bring much needed structure to this mobile site and future web applications we may bring.

I have made a comparision table where I have managed to bring the selection down to 2 - backbone and knockout.

I have been looking around the web and it seems that there is more support for backbone in general and maybe even more support for backbone with JQM.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/backbone-require.html

One thing I have noticed however is that backbone doesnt support view bindings (declarative approach) whereas knockout does - is this a massive bonus?

one of the main reasons for using a mv* for us is to get more structure - so I would like to use the library that will intergrate best with jQuery and especially jQuery mobile. neither of them seem to have that similar syntax...

Thanks

Comment: I also did a lot of research to find the best frameworks for my current project which is not mobile web but single page application for desktop browser. For me, the most important thing was two-way data binding between views and javascript model. As you mentioned, Backbone does not support data binding while knockout does. On the other hand, Backbone provide to invoke RESTful api easily while Knockout does not. However, I realized that this can be supported by  another great RESTful api client frameworks such as AmplifyJS. To sumup, my team is using Knockout with great satisfaction.

Comment: I've used them both and as far as I can say KO is better and faster to learn for small apps with few views, but as your project grows in size and complexity I think that Backbone offer a better structure. If you need view bindings for Backbone I suggest to try [Backbone Modelbinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder). Also, another plugin that can help you to bootstrap your development and avoid to write a lot of boilerplate code is [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/).